# iOS: How to achieve relative layout

Tags: android, iphone, ios, android-relativelayout, autolayout

I'm trying to make an iOS version of my Android app. It contains text that looks like this:

[image]

There are three labels: title, author, and publication year. I need to display the full title, which may be several lines long. However long the title is, I want the author label to be directly below the title, and the pub. year directly below that.

In Android, I just used relative layouts to achieve this effect. How can I do this in iOS? Can Auto Layout do this for me somehow? If not, do you have any suggestions for effectively displaying this information in iOS? Preferably I'd like to achieve this using the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS you use InterfaceBuilder IB for layouts - it's drag and drop - not like Android layouts.
Search for IB tutorials - it is really straight forward and you see what you get:-)

Comment: .. but the absolute layouts it produces are not so good for the case where, e.g. the title sometimes takes up two or three lines and you want the items below to move to make space.

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with InterfaceBuilder; that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Do you know the new autolayout Features In the New IB? This is exactly what you Need

Comment: How do I do relative positioning using autolayout?

Comment: Check the new "Use Autolayout" check box in IB and add the constraints you need - may want to look for a tutorial or watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dkr9eKxlMAk

Comment: keep in mind this is only supported by ios 6. you will have a problem with older iOS versions. one way to handle this for older versions is to adjust the view yourself in code when the data in it is updated.

Comment: ...keep in mind that with iOS it's save to assume that > 98% will update to every new iOS ... :-)  - as opposed to Android :-(

Answer (score 0):

I also searched quite some time a way to achieve android-like layouts in iOS (without the hassle of computing every positions for each subviews).

I eventually gave up and coded a fast equivalent of VerticalLayout and HorizontalLayout. Here's the repo (it's ARC compliant) :

https://github.com/kirualex/iOS-Layout-helper

It's sketchy but it does the work !

Comment: iOS-Layout-helper has been discontinued. Use [CSLinearLayoutView](https://github.com/scalessec/CSLinearLayoutView) instead.

Answer (score -3):

Put simply relative layout organises items on the screen relative to something else. Like linear layout, relative layout is commonly used by android developers. I myself do like this layout and have used in the development of my applications before. See

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html for more information on relative layouts.

Comment: While true, this does not answer the question.

Comment: This has zero relevance to the question, this should be down voted.